Can't Delete Cells/Rows/Columns when Sheet is Protected - Protect specific Range in Excel
I have a basic setup range in Excel like so:

In reality, its more complex, but lets use the above as an example. I have formulas inside the first column which I want to leave empty so it can be copied to the right when new entries are added.
Please note: I am not able to change the structure too much of this sheet due to internal requirements.
What I want to do is block people from inputting any data/deleting the first blank column.
So far, I've tried this, which almost worked, but I can't seem to enable users to be able to use the "Delete" function.
Steps to protect range:

Select entire worksheet, format cells, protection tab, unselect "Locked"
Select range to protect, format cells, protection tab, select "Locked"
Go to "Review" tab, select "Protect Sheet", give all options including "Delete columns/rows" and activate (I've tried with and without password, but I need it to have no password and I can't use VBA)
This allows users to copy the blank range and paste it as I wanted and edit other cells, but the "Delete" button is greyed out no matter where I select.


How I protect just this empty range and/or allow deletion of cells on protected sheet?
Note: I can't use VBA, but I'm open to alternative methods of protection

Btw, I think this is more of a question for SuperUser Exchange, since there's no programming involved.

Start without the protected sheet;
Select the cells that you want to be able to delete, right click any one of them;
Click 'Cell Properties'; in the tab 'protection' (last one), take the lock off of them (the first checkbox);
Protect your sheet.
This should do it.

Now, little side note: inserted rows/columns are automatically locked, thus cannot be altered; deleting the entire row makes you restart this procedure; when cells are not locked, they can be emptied (select and press delete on your keyboard).
So I'd recommend you to only select the first two options. (of course, depending on what you want to achieve, play a little with it).

That sounds like exactly what I already did

@FreeSoftwareServers Yeah it does, I've read through your question again, and it seems that's all you need? However, you can't 'delete' cells within a locked sheet (as far as I know); because when you delete them, all cells around have to move, which would in turn possibly place cells within the unlockerd area. However, you can clear them of content, by selecting them and pressing delete on your keyboard (or right clicking and then 'clear content', right below delete).  Hope it helps.
